# What is "Accelerator" in SAP Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I try to figure out `SAP Hybris` terminology and met the term "Accelerator".

`SAP`'s dictionary says:

```
An implementation template that facilitates the creation and maintenance of omnichannel commerce solutions.
```

But it is more some marketing text then definition. I don't understand what it is. Is it some java module which can be modified? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

An accelerator is working store front backend & UI implementation for specific industry. For example: b2c, b2b, telco.